# ios - How to use two bezier path in a same view?

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I am using UIBezierPath to cut a hole in my image using this.

```
UIBezierPath *currentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    CGPoint tempPoint = CGPointMake(leftEyePos.x+30,leftEyePos.y-25);
    [currentPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)];
    tempPoint = CGPointMake(leftEyePos.x-40,leftEyePos.y-25);
    [currentPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)];
    tempPoint = CGPointMake(leftEyePos.x-40,leftEyePos.y+10);
    [currentPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)];
    tempPoint = CGPointMake(leftEyePos.x+30,leftEyePos.y+10);
    [currentPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)];
    tempPoint = CGPointMake(leftEyePos.x+30, leftEyePos.y-25);
    [currentPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)];
```

and this

```
// Create an image context containing the original UIImage.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(filteredImage.size);
    [filteredImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    // Clip to the bezier path and clear that portion of the image.
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddPath(context,currentPath.CGPath);
    CGContextAddPath(context,nextPath.CGPath);
    CGContextClip(context);
    CGContextClearRect(context,CGRectMake(0,0,filteredImage.size.width,filteredImage.size.height));

    // Build a new UIImage from the image context.
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

What I want is to use another path. How can I achieve this? I tried creating new UIBezierPath like this: `UIBezierPath *newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];` and I add the CGPoint again:

```
CGPoint mouthTempPoint = CGPointMake(mouthPos.x-30, mouthPos.y-10);

    [newPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(mouthTempPoint.x, mouthTempPoint.y)];
    mouthTempPoint = CGPointMake(mouthPos.x+30, mouthPos.y-10);
    [newPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(mouthTempPoint.x, mouthTempPoint.y)];
    mouthTempPoint = CGPointMake(mouthPos.x+30, mouthPos.y-30);
    [newPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(mouthTempPoint.x, mouthTempPoint.y)];
    mouthTempPoint = CGPointMake(mouthPos.x-30, mouthPos.y-30);
    [newPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(mouthTempPoint.x, mouthTempPoint.y)];
    mouthTempPoint = CGPointMake(mouthPos.x-30, mouthPos.y-10);
    [newPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(mouthTempPoint.x, mouthTempPoint.y)];
```

But Im getting an error. My error is `<Error>: void CGPathAddLineToPoint(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGFloat, CGFloat): no current point.`

Can someone help me?

Comment: You don't have a starting `moveToPoint` in the second example?

Comment: I just copy the other bezier path and cg point. I just change the variable name. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

See what you start path on first code part

```
CGPoint tempPoint = CGPointMake(leftEyePos.x+30,leftEyePos.y-25);
    [currentPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y)];
```

to begin new line you must have a **start point**

Comment: This is my start point on my second bezier path `CGPoint mouthTempPoint = CGPointMake(mouthPos.x-30, mouthPos.y-10);`. What am I missing here or i can't use two bezier path in one view?

Comment: there is no limit for bezier path on view, about your start point yes you create it, but where you call `moveToPoint:` for it?

Comment: I check the UIBezier reference and saw the moveToPoint: method. This is I'm looking for. Thanks.